# Spring boot: environment variables configuration ignored

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-configuration

Into my local:

```
$ env | grep SPRING_SECURITY
SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATIONSERVER_CLIENT_OIDC_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_CLIENT_ID=rdocelec
SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATIONSERVER_CLIENT_OIDC_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_CLIENT_SECRET={noop}xxx
SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATIONSERVER_CLIENT_OIDC_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION_METHODS_0=client_secret_basic
SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATIONSERVER_CLIENT_OIDC_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_AUTHORIZATION_GRANT_TYPES_0=client_credentials
SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATIONSERVER_CLIENT_OIDC_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_SCOPES_0=api
SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATIONSERVER_CLIENT_OIDC_CLIENT_REQUIRE_AUTHORIZATION_CONSENT=true
```

Above environment values are binded correctly:

```
❯ http localhost:9090/actuator/configprops -b | yq '.contexts.application.beans."spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.server.servlet.OAuth2AuthorizationServerProperties".inputs'
```

```yaml
{
  "client": {
    "oidc-client": {
      "registration": {
        "clientId": {
          "value": "******",
          "origin": "System Environment Property \"SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATIONSERVER_CLIENT_OIDC_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_CLIENT_ID\""
        },
        "clientSecret": {
          "value": "******",
          "origin": "System Environment Property \"SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATIONSERVER_CLIENT_OIDC_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_CLIENT_SECRET\""
        },
        "clientAuthenticationMethods": [
          {
            "value": "******",
            "origin": "System Environment Property \"SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATIONSERVER_CLIENT_OIDC_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION_METHODS_0\""
          }
        ],
        "authorizationGrantTypes": [
          {
            "value": "******",
            "origin": "System Environment Property \"SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATIONSERVER_CLIENT_OIDC_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_AUTHORIZATION_GRANT_TYPES_0\""
          }
        ],
        "redirectUris": [],
        "postLogoutRedirectUris": [],
        "scopes": [
          {
            "value": "******",
            "origin": "System Environment Property \"SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATIONSERVER_CLIENT_OIDC_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_SCOPES_0\""
          }
        ]
      },
      "requireProofKey": {},
      "requireAuthorizationConsent": {
        "value": "******",
        "origin": "System Environment Property \"SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATIONSERVER_CLIENT_OIDC_CLIENT_REQUIRE_AUTHORIZATION_CONSENT\""
      },
      "token": {
        "authorizationCodeTimeToLive": {},
        "accessTokenTimeToLive": {},
        "accessTokenFormat": {},
        "deviceCodeTimeToLive": {},
        "reuseRefreshTokens": {},
        "refreshTokenTimeToLive": {},
        "idTokenSignatureAlgorithm": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "endpoint": {
    "authorizationUri": {},
    "deviceAuthorizationUri": {},
    "deviceVerificationUri": {},
    "tokenUri": {},
    "jwkSetUri": {},
    "tokenRevocationUri": {},
    "tokenIntrospectionUri": {},
    "oidc": {
      "logoutUri": {},
      "clientRegistrationUri": {},
      "userInfoUri": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Nevertheless, into my pod:

```
+ kubectl exec -it oauthz-7d9fbdbf6f-4g8cf -- bash
oauthz-7d9fbdbf6f-4g8cf:/$ env | grep SPRING_SECURITY
SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATIONSERVER_CLIENT_OIDC_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_SCOPES_0=api
SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATIONSERVER_CLIENT_OIDC_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_CLIENT_SECRET={noop}xxx
SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATIONSERVER_CLIENT_OIDC_CLIENT_REQUIRE_AUTHORIZATION_CONSENT=true
SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATIONSERVER_CLIENT_OIDC_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_AUTHORIZATION_GRANT_TYPES_0=client_credentials
SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATIONSERVER_CLIENT_OIDC_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION_METHODS_0=client_secret_basic
SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATIONSERVER_CLIENT_OIDC_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_CLIENT_ID=rdocelec
```

When I'm trying to look up them on actuator:

```
❯ http http://des.keycloak.espaidoc-keycloak.apps.ocpdes.t-systems.es/actuator/configprops -b | yq '.contexts.application.beans."spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.server.servlet.OAuth2AuthorizationServerProperties"'
```

```yaml
{
  "prefix": "spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver",
  "properties": {
    "client": {},
    "endpoint": {
      "authorizationUri": "******",
      "deviceAuthorizationUri": "******",
      "deviceVerificationUri": "******",
      "tokenUri": "******",
      "jwkSetUri": "******",
      "tokenRevocationUri": "******",
      "tokenIntrospectionUri": "******",
      "oidc": {
        "logoutUri": "******",
        "clientRegistrationUri": "******",
        "userInfoUri": "******"
      }
    }
  },
  "inputs": {
    "client": {},
    "endpoint": {
      "authorizationUri": {},
      "deviceAuthorizationUri": {},
      "deviceVerificationUri": {},
      "tokenUri": {},
      "jwkSetUri": {},
      "tokenRevocationUri": {},
      "tokenIntrospectionUri": {},
      "oidc": {
        "logoutUri": {},
        "clientRegistrationUri": {},
        "userInfoUri": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I had a similar problem when mixing `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap` and `spring-cloud-starter-config` in the used artifact. Do you use a config-server or do you only do injects via Environment Variables?

Comment: I'm only using environment variables ...